# How to upgrade Civix v21.04

Tags: upgrade, civix

I am trying to upgrade the Civix code in one of my extensions but it does not seem to be working.  Civix is currently at v21.04.1, and the latest version is 23.08.  I am following the directions in the Civix UPGRADE.md file in the 21.04 version on Github at `https://github.com/totten/civix/blob/v21.04.1/UPGRADE.md`

The generate:module command runs OK, and says that it is writing `[my ext].civix.php` but afterwards `civix -v` still reports the same version, and git reports no changes have been made to that file (a space has been removed from one line in `info.xml`).  See the attached screenshot.

[image]

Any help gratefully received.
Tony

Comment: The command is `civix upgrade` not `civix generate:module` to upgrade your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`civix -v` tells you the version of civix that you have on your machine (not the version of civix that the extension has been updated to). So the problem is your local version of civix is not up to date.

As it says in the [civix readme](https://github.com/totten/civix/blob/v21.04.1/README.md), to update civix, you just need to download the latest version. Once you've done that, do `civix -v` to confirm you're on the latest version and then you can follow the [instructions to upgrade your extension](https://github.com/totten/civix/blob/v23.08.2/UPGRADE.md) (note these are the up to date instructions, the ones you linked to are out of date).

You can check the civix version of the extension by looking in the `info.xml` file in the extension.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  My problem in not thinking clearly enough.